# NestJs Microservices Communicating With Other Non NestJs Microservices Through ClientProxy

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I want to know if it is possible to make a request from a NestJs microservice to other non NestJs microservices (for example: Spring boot microservice) using NestJs ClientProxy. I have googled for a while but i haven't seen any post talking about such communication.

Any idea, suggestion or link to a post will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That should indeed be possible - basically one of the main benefits to having microservices is for them to be language agnostic.

Basically you are leveraging the messaging broker functionality across microservices - main thing you need to take into account is to use the same queue configurations for both the producer and the consumer(s) side